# Proper way to run an action before navigation using NavigationLink(value:) initializer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to find the correct way to execute an action before navigation to a specific screen occurs. I have something like this:

I have something like this:

```
 var nextButtonView: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: PathState.Destination.someEnum) {
            Text("form-next-button-title".localized)
                .addNextButtonStyle(enabled: !viewModel.isNextButtonDisabled)

        }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({ _ in
            viewModel.onNextButtonTap()
        }))

        .disabled(viewModel.isNextButtonDisabled)
    }
```

Now, when I looked at this example from the documentation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var message = "Message"
    let newGesture = TapGesture().onEnded {
        print("Gesture on VStack.")
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:25) {
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Gesture on image.")
                }
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(newGesture)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .border(Color.purple)
    }
}
```

The `VStack's` gesture is executed first, then the image gesture. This seems fine to me because I would prefer to execute `onNextButtonTap()` method first and then navigate to the next screen. However, I'm a bit uncertain about what really happens and which action executes first, or if this is even the correct way to run an action before navigation.

So, my question is, is there some other way to achieve this, or is this how it should be done?

Comment: How about using a `Button` to do the navigation instead? When the button is tapped, you can programmatically navigate by appending to a navigation path.

Comment: @Sweeper Yup, I wasn't thinking in that direction. Completely worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you'll have a better time if you use the `View` struct as the view model since that's what it is.